# How to quiet warning output of fzero command Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a code in which I'm finding solutions of a non-linear equation.

I'm using the command `fzero`, however in some regions the equation has imaginary solutions as well and I get the following output

```
Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
because complex function value encountered during search.
(Function value at -10.6164 is 0.92591+0.33977i.)
```

How can I quiet this output, so it will not appear in the command line? I'm searching the solution in very small intervals and this makes the calculation very slow...

I've tried so far (from the Matlab documentation) using

```
sol = fzero(func,x0,optimset('FunValCheck','off'));
```

but it did not help. any suggestions?

Comment: If it's a warning: `warning off` should do the trick. Bit overkill though, since it silences *all* warnings until you restart MATLAB. You can probably find a warning ID somewhere and turn just that warning off

Comment: @Adriaan, I've tried. does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add `'Display','off'` arguments to `optimset`:

```
sol = fzero(fun, x0, optimset('FunValCheck', 'off', 'Display', 'off'));
```

According to [fzero](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) documentation, the default is `'notify'`:

> **Display** - 'notify' (default) displays output only if the function does not converge.

When the output converges to `NaN` or `Inf` or **complex** value, the function displays a message.